# Staricase demand curve

Tags: microeconomics, demand

I wonder what horizontal lines in staircase demand curve represent. I understand that we construct the demand curve considering WTP of each buyer. But why do we connect the points as horizontal lines? Is there an intuition for these lines. I cannot understand what they represent because there is no quantity between 0 and 1, they are all integers. Can't we just eliminate those lines and keep them empty or do we connect the points just for the sake of having curve shape without any underlying intuition?

[image: Staircase demand curve]

Comment: How else would you connect them? If you connect them with straight lines, that means that halfway in between, half a person will buy the thing.

Comment: this function is defined by person 1 buying the thing if the price is less than P1, person 2 buying it if the price is less than P2, etc. There is no rule that P1 will buy half a thing if the price is a bit higher than he wants.

Comment: My question is: how would you interpret if someone asked what the horizontal line drawn above x axis between 0 and 1 represent? Is there any intuition or not?

Comment: changing the price doesn't change the demand, until you get all the way to a certain price, then the demand jumps suddenly by 1 whole person